# Can we copy link list to an array in o(1) (both have same size n)?

Tags: data-structures

Can we copy link list to an array in O(1) (both have same size n)?

i.e no of element in link list and size of array is same.

Comment: What do *you* think? Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

No ... while the copying operation itself is an O(1) operation, it occurs N times, therefore the complexity of the entire operation becomes O(N).

Answer (score 2):

One short answer. No. 
Maybe your question is incomplete and some constraint is missing, but like it is, the answer is obviously no.

Answer (score 1):

No: if have to copy `n` elements you will need `n` operations. You can traverse the list in O(n) and insert each element in the array in O(1). You can't expect a constant time to process a variable number of elements.

Comment: And that's assuming you know `n` so you don't need to grow the array mid-copy.

Answer (score 0):

## No.

Unless you redefine a little what you consider a `Linked List` and `Array`. Technically you only have to make a precondition.

If you had: **Immutable Structures**

Then every `Linked List` could be an `Array` (if you are at element `n`, it is O(1) to go to `n-1` and `n+1`, so the "reading" part would be equivalent). At this point, if you split the "contained" from the "container", you could copy an `Array` to an `Array`, or an `Array` to a `Linked List`, or a `Linked List` to an `Array` or a `Linked List` to a `Linked List` all in O(1). From splitting the container from the contained I mean (in C#):

```
struct MyArray
{
    private int[] baseArray;

    public int this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return baseArray[index];
        }
    }
}

struct MyList
{
    private int[] baseArray;

    public Tuple<int, int> First()
    {
         return new Tuple<int, int>(0, baseArray[0]);
    }

    public Tuple<int, int> Next(Tuple<int, int> current)
    {
         return new Tuple<int, int>(current.Item1 + 1, baseArray(current.Item1 + 1));
    }
}
```

With a constructor that accepts a souce of data, a copy constructor that simply copies the reference to baseArray (this would be O(1) because we are copying only the reference) and all the other necessary methods.

(This answer more a provocation and/or a thinking out of the box)

(I'm using C# `struct`s to point out the fact that they are very light objects. The real "meat" is "inside" the `baseArray`. These structs are little more than a reference + the methods)

Comment: Is copying references really the same thing as "copying the list"?

Comment: @Jason `string a = "Hello"; string b = a;` Is copying the reference of the string really the same thing as "copying the string"? .NET can do it because the string is immutable.

Comment: @xanatos - assuming everything is immutable is a cop out - there'd be roughly no reason to ever use a linked list over an array in the first place.  Assuming that a List is immutable means the copy is O(1) - until such time as you do ANYTHING to it, at which case you'll have an O(n) copy to make the new version. And if you weren't going to do anything with it, why would you transform it in the first place?

Comment: @James You know, immutable structures have their place. F# has immutable arrays and mutable lists. Immutable Linked Lists are surely quite useless, especially when in the end they are based on an Array unless they are more like an abstraction to make the programmer use the elements "one at a time". As an example of something mure usefull. Let's say we have a LL of `Lazy<int>`, where each element is lazily calculated on the previous element (for example X[i] = 2*X[i - 1]) and X[0]=1. This would be perfect for a LL (because you have to traverse i - 1 elements to see the i element).